# Does unfinished create-react-app affect webpack server?

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app, npm-start, npm-package

I created a react application using vs-code terminal command

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Dependencies were still running when my battery went off.

Will it affect my we pack development server?
[Screenshot of my error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtKjh.png)

I tried starting the application using

```
npm start
```

but it took more than normal time to start the development server on localHost:3000.

Then at the bottom of the terminal window, webpack showed installed with 2 errors.